# Symfony Warning: class_implements(): Class pdo_sqlsrv does not exist and could not be loaded

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

I am learning symfony on openclassroom. 
I have an ubuntu linux and need to connect on mssql srv.
-> the config.yml having driver_class: pdo_sqlsrv

When running

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I got

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>     Warning: class_implements(): Class pdo_sqlsrv does not exist and could not be loaded

In my `php.ini`, I have well

```
project # php  -m | grep pdo
pdo_sqlite
pdo_sqlsrv
```

and the following PHP code runs and display the table records.

```
  <?php
$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=10.32.1.11,1433;Database=gaudc";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, "sa", "Genesys*");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM gaudctable";
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    print_r($row);

?>
```

I have no idea what to do more and I am getting crazy with this.
Does someone here have an idea ?

Kind regards,

Comment: what does `php bin/console doctrine:database:create --verbose` say?

Comment: Also have you tried `php composer.phar dump-autoload -o`, be sure to also clear you symfony cache `php bin/console cache:clear` (or manually delete) `/var/cache/dev` after updating composer, which may resolve an issue with `/var/cache/dev/classes`.

Comment: Lastly please post your `/app/config.yml` section of `doctrine.dbal`